# How do I display select field values rather than their associated stored integers in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Say for example I allow my users to select their gender and marital status in form and then post that form so their selections are stored in the database.

**A form could look like this:**

```
<select id="profile_marital_status" name="profile[marital_status]"><option value=""> Select</option>
<option value="1">Single</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Dating</option>
<option value="3">In relationship</option>
<option value="4">Married</option>
<option value="5">Living Together</option>
<option value="6">Divorced</option>
<option value="7">Separated</option>
<option value="8">Widowed</option></select><br />
```

To access this and display the stored data in a view I would do this @profile.marital_status. The problem is it will display what's stored in the db which would be an integer.

To solve this issue I'm currently doing this with helper methods:

```
def get_gender(number)
  if number == 1
    'Male'
  elsif number == 2
    'Female'
  end
end

def get_marital_status(number)
  if number == 1
    'Single'
  elsif number == 2
    'Dating'
  elsif number == 3
    'In relationship'
  elsif number == 4
    'Married'
  elsif number == 5
    'Living Together'
  elsif number == 6
    'Divorced'
  elsif number == 7
    'Separated'
  elsif number == 8
    'Widowed'
  end
end
```

**Then in view:**

```
= get_gender(@profile.gender)
= get_marital_status(@profile.marital_status)
```

This seems wrong though because when I get to the stage when I need to display back the country the user registered I don't see myself typing out a long if statement with a list of countries.

There must be a much more practical sensible way of doing this. I would appreciate any solutions for how I can display back the select field values e.g. "Male" instead of what was stored in the DB e.g. 1 or "Female" 2.

Update:

**In my ApplicationsHelper I have full list of countries stored in an array:**

```
 COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE   = [
      ['Any', nil],
      ['United Kingdom', 826],
      ['United States', 840],
      ['-----------', ' '],
      ['Afghanistan', 4],
      ['Ãland Islands', 248],
      ['Albania', 8],
      ['Algeria', 12],
      ['American Samoa', 16],
      ['Andorra', 20],
      ['Angola', 24],
      ['Anguilla', 660],
      ['Antarctica', 10],
      ['Antigua and Barbuda', 28],
      ['Argentina', 32],
      ['Armenia', 51],
      ['Aruba', 533],
```

**Putting this in my view:**

```
= ApplicationHelper::COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE[@profile.country]
```

**Shows this result in my view:**

```
 ["Sudan", 729]
```

I just need to figure out how to pull out just the country name, or some how filter out everything but the string.

I already typed out the a full list of country names and their ISO codes a few months ago so this will save a lot of time.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is another way that Andrew Marshall didn't mention: you could assign the string values to an array and use that for displaying the various option tags. It allows easy editing if you ever change them.

`array = ['Male', 'Female']` and later `array[Integer(@profile.gender)]`.

Comment: Just tack a `.first` or `[0]` on the end (so you get `ApplicationHelper::COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE[@profile.country].first`) and you get the country name. `.second` or `[1]` will give you the ISO code (though I dunno what that is).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Seeing as I created these arrays months back when I was building the forms for editing a profile I won't need to type anything out again. I can just use the integers stored in the DB along with those arrays to get the result I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, your code could be refactored to use `case`:

```
def get_gender(number)
  case number
  when 1 then 'Male'
  when 2 then 'Female'
  end
end

def get_marital_status(number)
  case number
  when 1 then 'Single'
  when 2 then 'Dating'
  when 3 then 'In relationship'
  when 4 then 'Married'
  when 5 then 'Living Together'
  when 6 then 'Divorced'
  when 7 then 'Separated'
  when 8 then 'Widowed'
  end
end
```

Second, the contents of the `<option>` tag are not submitted with the form, so there's absolutely no way to access them on the server. You have the following options:

- Leave it the way it is.
- Change the value stored in the database to the actual string value instead of a number, that way you remove the obfuscation at the cost of some space in your database.
- Denormalize the field, making a separate table for the values, so the number stored is now the ID in the other table.

Comment: I think your last suggestion is the one that makes more sense. Rendering the form will be mutch easier, also changing the accepted values will be easier and it adds validations.

Comment: Not sure I understand the last suggestion clearly. I may end up going with a combination of Mizuho's suggestion and what I'm already doing.

Comment: @LondonGuy You'd make another table for, say, `marital_statuses`, which would have the text values. Then you'd store the foreign key in the model you're currently storing it in.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution. I created arrays some months back for dealing with the editing of user profile details so I tapped into those arrays and got the result I want using the stored integers from the db.

**In my ApplicationsHelper I have full list of countries stored in an array:**

```
 COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE   = [
      ['Any', nil],
      ['United Kingdom', 826],
      ['United States', 840],
      ['-----------', ' '],
      ['Afghanistan', 4],
      ['Ãland Islands', 248],
      ['Albania', 8],
      ['Algeria', 12],
      ['American Samoa', 16],
      ['Andorra', 20],
      ['Angola', 24],
      ['Anguilla', 660],
      ['Antarctica', 10],
      ['Antigua and Barbuda', 28],
      ['Argentina', 32],
      ['Armenia', 51],
      ['Aruba', 533],
```

**Putting this in my view:**

```
= ApplicationHelper::COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE[@profile.country].first
```

**Shows this result in my view:**

```
 United Kingdom
```

Comment: This array *definitely* belongs in the model, not a helper.