# Why am I getting undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass when trying to pull value from array in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I created arrays some months back for dealing with the editing of user profile details. When displaying back users registered countries I tap into the array and get the result I want using the stored integers from the db.

**In my User model I have full list of countries stored in an array:**

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   

     COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE   = [
          ['Any', nil],
          ['United Kingdom', 826],
          ['United States', 840],
          ['-----------', ' '],
          ['Afghanistan', 4],
          ['Ãland Islands', 248],
          ['Albania', 8],
          ['Algeria', 12],
          ['American Samoa', 16],
          ['Andorra', 20],
          ['Angola', 24],
          ['Anguilla', 660],
          ['Antarctica', 10],
          ['Antigua and Barbuda', 28],
          ['Argentina', 32],
          ['Armenia', 51],
          ['Aruba', 533],
```

**Put this in my view:**

```
= User::COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE[@profile.country].first
```

**Shows this result in my view e.g.:**

```
 United Kingdom
```

The issue I'm having is with the large country array. For some profiles it seems to work but most I get this error:

```
 undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
```

I know for a fact @profile.country for every profile isn't nil so not sure where this error is coming from. If I remove the call to the array and just have @profile.country in my view it shows the stored integer as expected.

I'm not experiencing this issue with my other arrays.. e.g. martial_status, gender, sexuality. So I'm wondering whether this could be something to do with the size of the array and memory or something? I don't know that's why I'm asking.

I'm close to taking another route which was suggested in another question I asked by creating another table with the country names stored and use the integer stored in the profiles table to get the correct country from the countries table. I wanted to avoid this though because that's 2 calls to the db when I originally had 1.

Any idea what could be wrong with my current code? I can't figure out why it's working on some profiles and not others.  I don't need to check for a stored country integer because I created a rake task that updated every user with a country.

Other question: [How do I display select field values rather than their associated stored integers in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972302/how-do-i-display-select-field-values-rather-than-their-associated-stored-integer)

Hope you can help

Also if you mark me down please give a reason. I'm here to learn from my mistakes and maybe my mistakes can help others who come across my question with similar issues.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
User::COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE.rassoc(@profile.country).try(:first)
```

Comment: I was searching for the position in the whole array . It makes sense why this works. I just done a quick search on rassoc and try. Works fine thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a hash to make this `User::COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE[@profile.country].first` code work. Just replace your array with hash, for instance:

```
COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE   = {
 'Any' => nil,
 'United Kingdom' => 826,
 'United States' => 840,
 # ..etc.
}
```

..and don't forget to write a test for this code ;)

Comment: jdoe's solution was much quicker for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`ary[index]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) returns an element by *index*, so

```
COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE[0] # => ['Any', nil]
COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE[1] # => ['United Kingdom', 826]
COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE[2] # => ['United States', 840]
```

If `@profile.country` is `826` then `COUNTRY_AND_ISO_CODE[@profile.country]` returns the 826th element from your array or `nil` if there's no such element.

Comment: Yep, figured that out shortly after posting the Q. I manually typed in numbers in place of @profile.country and clocked on to the pattern of returned results after the 3rd try. Thanks